# Can't make bash default shell

Tags: command-line, bash, zsh

I installed ZSH and didn't like it and I want to revert back to bash. I uninstalled ZSH before I tried changing the default shell. I uninstalled ZSH and then ran the commands `chsh` and `sudo chsh --shell=/bin/bash $USERNAME` but it seems that no matter what commands I use to change the shell it still says that I'm using the ZSH shell when I run `echo $?`. I'm pretty new to Linux/Ubuntu so can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You do understand that the "shell", kept in `/etc/passwd` only applies at `login` time?

Comment: Have you logged out and back in after changing your login shell?

Answer (score 4):

you can take a look at the list of shells you have installed with:
cat /etc/shells

For example, to change current shell to bash, you can use the chsh command :
chsh -s /bin/bash

or use the usermod command to change the shell of a user:
sudo usermod -s /bin/bash putHereTheUserName

You can confirm the sheel of the user on /etc/passwd (it's the last element of each line):
cat /etc/passwd | grep putHereTheUserName

Answer (score 1):

Remove the old symlink first

```
sudo rm -v /bin/sh
```

Now, create a new symlink, assuming that `bash` is in `/bin` directory

```
sudo ln -sv /bin/bash /bin/sh
```

This should do the trick for you.

Comment: `/bin/sh` on Ubuntu is supposed to point to `/bin/dash`, and nobody uses `/bin/sh` as their login shell. This bad advice, and unrelated to the problem at hand.

Comment: @muru FYI on my Ubuntu  `/bin/sh` is linked to `/bin/bash` by default and it uses `bash` as the default login shell.

Comment: Then you must have made it so. Ubuntu has used `/bin/dash` as `/bin/sh` for **years**. FYI: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh And I said: nobody uses **`/bin/sh`** as their login shell.